# i wan to split a list into small lists inside the same list

Tags: python-3.x

i have a list 
i want to to make every 5 elements become in a list in the same list

```
input = ['Operating System: free dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 500 gb', 'Processor Family: amd e series', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: linux', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 7th generation core i3', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: mac', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 128 gb', 'Processor Family: intel core i5', 'Screen Size: 13 - 13.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 32 gb', 'Operating System: linux', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 256 gb', 'Processor Family: intel 7th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 13 - 13.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: linux', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 14 - 14.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: free dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 500 gb', 'Processor Family: intel celeron n3060', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: linux', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 7th generation core i3', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 500 gb', 'Processor Family: intel celeron n3350', 'Screen Size: 14 - 14.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 6 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 500 gb', 'Processor Family: intel celeron n3350', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 6 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: amd a6 series', 'Screen Size: 11 - 11.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 512 gb', 'Processor Family: intel 7th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15.6 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: mac', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 256 gb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 13 - 13.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 64 gb', 'Processor Family: intel quad core', 'Screen Size: 14 - 14.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 2 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 2 tb + 256 gb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: intel celeron dual core', 'Screen Size: 14 - 14.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 3 gb', 'Operating System: linux', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 6th generation core i3', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 2 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 7th generation core i3', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 2 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 12 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 500 gb', 'Processor Family: core i3 (6th generation)', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: free dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 500 gb', 'Processor Family: amd a4 series', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: intel cherrytrail', 'Screen Size: 11 - 11.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 2 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 7th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 2tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 2 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: intel cherrytrail', 'Screen Size: 11 - 11.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 2 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: intel pentium n4200', 'Screen Size: 13 - 13.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 3 gb', 'Operating System: dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 7th generation core i3', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 2 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: amd apu a4', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 500 gb', 'Processor Family: intel celeron', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: linux', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 500 gb', 'Processor Family: intel 6th generation core i3', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: mac', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 128 gb', 'Processor Family: intel 5th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 13 - 13.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 2 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 32 gb', 'Operating System: linux', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: mac', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 128 gb', 'Processor Family: intel core i5', 'Screen Size: 13 - 13.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: intel atom x5-z8350', 'Screen Size: 12 - 12.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 2 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 256 gb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 14 - 14.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 13 - 13.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: intel atom', 'Screen Size: 10 - 10.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 2 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: intel celeron n3060', 'Screen Size: 11 - 11.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: intel celeron n3060', 'Screen Size: 11 - 11.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel core i3', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: mac', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 128 gb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 13 - 13.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: intel atom', 'Screen Size: 14 - 14.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 2 gb']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
lst = ['Operating System: free dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 500 gb', 'Processor Family: amd e series', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: linux', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 7th generation core i3', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: mac', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 128 gb', 'Processor Family: intel core i5', 'Screen Size: 13 - 13.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 32 gb', 'Operating System: linux', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 256 gb', 'Processor Family: intel 7th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 13 - 13.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: linux', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 14 - 14.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: free dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 500 gb', 'Processor Family: intel celeron n3060', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: linux', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 7th generation core i3', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 500 gb', 'Processor Family: intel celeron n3350', 'Screen Size: 14 - 14.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 6 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 500 gb', 'Processor Family: intel celeron n3350', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 6 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: amd a6 series', 'Screen Size: 11 - 11.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 512 gb', 'Processor Family: intel 7th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15.6 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: mac', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 256 gb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 13 - 13.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 64 gb', 'Processor Family: intel quad core', 'Screen Size: 14 - 14.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 2 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 2 tb + 256 gb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: intel celeron dual core', 'Screen Size: 14 - 14.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 3 gb', 'Operating System: linux', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 6th generation core i3', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 2 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 7th generation core i3', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 2 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 12 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 500 gb', 'Processor Family: core i3 (6th generation)', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: free dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 500 gb', 'Processor Family: amd a4 series', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: intel cherrytrail', 'Screen Size: 11 - 11.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 2 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 7th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 2tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 2 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: intel cherrytrail', 'Screen Size: 11 - 11.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 2 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: intel pentium n4200', 'Screen Size: 13 - 13.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 3 gb', 'Operating System: dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 7th generation core i3', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 2 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: amd apu a4', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 500 gb', 'Processor Family: intel celeron', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: linux', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 500 gb', 'Processor Family: intel 6th generation core i3', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: mac', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 128 gb', 'Processor Family: intel 5th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 13 - 13.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 2 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 32 gb', 'Operating System: linux', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: mac', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 128 gb', 'Processor Family: intel core i5', 'Screen Size: 13 - 13.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: dos', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: intel atom x5-z8350', 'Screen Size: 12 - 12.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 2 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 256 gb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 14 - 14.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 13 - 13.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 16 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: intel atom', 'Screen Size: 10 - 10.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 2 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: intel celeron n3060', 'Screen Size: 11 - 11.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: intel celeron n3060', 'Screen Size: 11 - 11.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb', 'Processor Family: intel core i3', 'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 4 gb', 'Operating System: mac', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 128 gb', 'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i5', 'Screen Size: 13 - 13.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 8 gb', 'Operating System: windows', 'Hard Disk Capacity: 32 gb', 'Processor Family: intel atom', 'Screen Size: 14 - 14.9 inch', 'Memory Size: 2 gb']

from itertools import groupby

out = [[v[1] for v in g] for _, g in groupby(enumerate(lst), lambda k: k[0] // 5)]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['Operating System: free dos',
  'Hard Disk Capacity: 500 gb',
  'Processor Family: amd e series',
  'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch',
  'Memory Size: 4 gb'],
 ['Operating System: linux',
  'Hard Disk Capacity: 1 tb',
  'Processor Family: intel 8th generation core i7',
  'Screen Size: 15 - 15.9 inch',
  'Memory Size: 8 gb'],

...and so on.
```